# Self-Referencing C Struct

Tags: c, pointers, struct, self-reference

Can you have a structure in C that has elements of that same structure? My first attempt at implementing a binary search tree in C is the following:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct binary_tree_node {

    int value;
    struct binary_tree_node *left = null;
    struct binary_tree_node *right = null;

};

main() {

    struct binary_tree_node t;
    t.value = 12;

    struct binary_tree_node y;
    y.value = 44;
    t.left = &y;
}
```

I can't figure out what's wrong with this code, any help would be appreciated. I realize there are other questions on binary search implementations in C, but I'm trying to figure this out from scratch with my own code (and some guidance of course). Thanks!

Comment: what does the error message say?

Comment: It was saying "error: 'struct binary_tree_node' has no member named 'left'", but I removed the "= null" from the definition and it's at least compiling now.

Comment: The line # of the first error usually is the key to the whole problem.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Remove the `= null` in your struct declaration. You can declare the self-reference, but you cannot set it.

Answer (score 7):

This is the error message on gcc 4:

```
test.c:6: error: expected ‘:’, ‘,’, ‘;’, ‘}’ or ‘__attribute__’ before ‘=’ token
test.c: In function ‘main’:
test.c:18: error: ‘struct binary_tree_node’ has no member named ‘left’
```

Firstly, you `null` is `NULL` in C.
Secondly, you cannot set a value to an element in a struct inside the struct definition.

So, it would look something like this:

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct binary_tree_node {

    int value;
    struct binary_tree_node *left;
    struct binary_tree_node *right;

};

main() {

    struct binary_tree_node t;
    t.left = NULL;
    t.right = NULL;
    t.value = 12;

    struct binary_tree_node y;
    y.left = NULL;
    t.right = NULL;
    y.value = 44;
    t.left = &y;
}
```

Or, you can create a function to make left and right NULL,

```
#include <stdio.h>

struct binary_tree_node {

    int value;
    struct binary_tree_node *left;
    struct binary_tree_node *right;

};

void make_null(struct binary_tree_node *x) {
    x->left = NULL;
    x->right = NULL;
}

main() {

    struct binary_tree_node t;
    make_null(&t)
    t.value = 12;

    struct binary_tree_node y;
    make_null(&y);
    y.value = 44;
    t.left = &y;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You cannot define the values inside the struct when defining the struct. This code snippet may benefit your project:

```
typedef struct binary_tree_node
{
    int value;
    binary_tree left;
    binary_tree right;
} binary_tree_node, *binary_tree;

#define DATA(T) ((T)->value)
#define LEFT(T) ((T)->left)
#define RIGHT(T) ((T)->right)
```